# Choosing Inheritance Strategy - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

**if this question was aksed here, i surely couldnt find it, or it didnt particulary help me.**

i've read some tutorials and some questions for Inheritance Mapping, which couldnt quitely solve my questions.

Say i have an abstract class :

> User

And 3 more other subclasses :

> UserA, UserB, UserC

those all extend User.

Every Subclass has its own table, Superclass `User`, meanwhile, doesn't.

In my other class `Website` i have a ArrayList, or should i say Collections, of Users.

The list should fetch all users of the `Website`.

Which strategy should i use ? I thought of MappedSuperclass, but since in my `Website` class the List is of User type, so am not sure what to do here.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `Every Subclass has its own table, Superclass User, meanwhile, doesn't.` Be careful of this, all those common fields in the superclass could get duplicated in each subclass table which could lead to inconsistency as well as duplication. Consider re-thinking the approach and having a table for superclass then additional tables for more specific extension data

Comment: @Jimmy My ideas were overiding  the common fields, which aren't too many. Anyway i counldnt change the structures, since its an existing database. What would be your best solution ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JPA the Java implementation always depends on you own preferences and requirements, sometimes it is the matter of a choice.

Yes, @MappedSuperclass will do. 
You can have every child with unidirectional relationship to Website. Then you gonna have Website object inside your User class (with a bunch of annotations), which will map to a database as foreign_key field (presume you are using SQL storage and 'Repositories' DAO abstraction from JPA).

It is not necessary to store a collection of users inside Website class. Just think if you really need it - it can be a mess to support consistency.
But there are cases where you need bidirectional relationship. When you store objects in memory (for caching purposes for example) you'll probably need to have this collection. In this case why not to have 'User' collection? You will fetch data through dedicated repositories(or even if you're not using those, any other way will be using 'User' tables with foreign_key, not the 'Website' table) anyway.

So, for example with the use of Spring Data JPA you can define a unidirectional relationship in a superclass and use 'repositories' next way(and bidirectional example you can find anywhere in the internet, so I am not providing it):

```
@Entity
public class SuperUser extends User {   
   ...
}

@Entity
public class BasicUser extends User {   
   ...
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class User implements Serializable {      

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "website_uuid", nullable = false)
    protected Website website;

    ...   
}

@Entity
public class Website implements Serializable {   

   ...
}


@Repository
public interface SuperUserRepository extends CrudRepository<SuperUser, Long> {

   Iterable<SuperUser> findByWebsite(Website website);

}

@Repository
public interface BasicUserRepository extends CrudRepository<BasicUser, Long> {

   Iterable<BasicUser> findByWebsite(Website website);

}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will try it later today !

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for seems a typical "Table-per-concrete-class" inheritance strategy.  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-table-per-class

In older version of the user guide, it has mentioned that separate table will be mapped for each non-abstract classes. In the latest document the "non-abstract" part is not mentioned but I believe it still works similarly.

So it looks something like:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract class User {...}

@Entity
class UserA extends User {...}

@Entity
class UserB extends User  {...}

@Entity
class UserC extends User  {...}
```

But you should be aware of this inheritance strategy usually gives inefficient query as internally it is using `union`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but i think this may not work because i dont have a table for the superclass.

Comment: That's what i mentioned: in the old (hibernate 3.3) document, it mentioned separate table is used for each concrete (non abstract) class. So you don't need table for your abstract superclass. Dunno if behaviour has changed though.